# How to filter HTML to be written to a new document, removing certain classes and/or IDs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Here, I attempt to make a new document with JS:

```
  objDoc.open();
  objDoc.write( "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">" );
  objDoc.write( "<html>" );
  objDoc.write( "<body>" );
  objDoc.write( "<head>" );
  objDoc.write( "<title>" );
  objDoc.write( document.title );
  objDoc.write( "</title>" );
  objDoc.write( jStyleDiv.html() );
  objDoc.write( "</head>" );
  objDoc.write( this.html() );
  objDoc.write( "</body>" );
  objDoc.write( "</html>" );
  objDoc.close();
```

Before I close the document (and probably after I write the html of another document I have in memory to the body of the new document), I would like to remove any elements that match a certain class and/or ID. jQuery solutions are OK. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside: I'm pretty sure the opening `<body>` should be after the ending `</head>` to be valid XHTML, even Transitional.

Comment: Use a template, for goodness' sake.

Comment: very true... very true... whops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution AresAvatar is suggesting is correct with one addition that solves the problem that you mention: The jQuery command to execute is

```
$(".myclass", objDoc).remove();
```

the second parameter to the jQuery is the context in which the command is executed. This way it is not applied in the entire page! See the URL below from the docs of jQuery.

api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Pan

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

```
$(".myclass").remove();
```

or

```
$("#myID").remove();
```

**Edit**: This does not alter CSS.  The CSS-like notations such as ".myclass" are a jQuery method of selecting nodes, that uses the css-like notation so that programmers use a familiar method of selecting DOM nodes.  The remove() API removes all matching nodes from the DOM.  So for example, execute $(".myclass").remove() and you will get:

**Before exec of $(".myclass").remove()**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .myclass {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="myclass">Paragraph one</p>
        <p>Paragraph two</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**After exec of $(".myclass").remove()**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .myclass {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Paragraph two</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but this would remove the classes from the current document too. I did give you an upvote though, I should have been more clear in my question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this.  The remove() API does not alter CSS, if that's what you meant by "remove classes".  The API only removes nodes from the DOM.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain more exactly what remove() does.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been pretty unclear. I understand how removeClass() and remove() work. I mean to say that $(".myclass").remove(); would also remove the elements with "myclass" on my existing document. I want to target only my newly created document. I will try $(".myclass", objDoc).remove(); as @Panais suggests.

Comment: OK, you meant you wanted to remove from the "new" document.  Yes, Panais' answer is more correct for that.